# VBScript to Open Powerpoint and Run Macro

Tags: vbscript, macros, powerpoint

I am trying to run a VBScript that opens powerpoint and runs a macro named UpdateandBreaklinks. The Script that I am running is as follows:

```
Dim oApp
Dim oPres
Dim oSlide

Set oApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
oApp.visible = true
Set oPres = oApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\PPwithLinks.pptm")
Set oSlide = oPres.Slides(1).Duplicate
oApp.Run "PPwithLinks.pptm!UpdateandBreaklinks"
```

This Gets the script to Run and open Powerpoint, however the Macro is not Ran. I get an error on this line:

```
oApp.Run "PPwithLinks.pptm!UpdateandBreaklinks"
```

I have tried to adjust it to this:

```
oApp.Run "UpdateandBreaklinks"
```

But I still get the same error. The error reads as:

```
Application.Run: Invalid request. Sub or funtion not defined.
Code: 80048240
```

I have researched the problem and all I can find is that people have remedied this same issue with the code above. I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

I have further tested the problem and I am now at this point:

So, I created a new pptm, I created a new macro for MsgBox "Hello" within the pptm. When I call the pptm to be opened with VBS, the pptm opens and I still get the error.

BUT, testing further, if I have opened the pptm first and then call the VBS the macro does run.(It opens another instance of the program as a [Read-Only] and runs the macro.)

Also, if I just open the pptm from the VBS(delete the line that runs the macro) and then try to run the Macro manually within PowerPoint then I get the following error: "Because of your security settings, macros have been disabled." 
I go into the Macro Security settings and they have not been changed, so it appears to me that when VBS Opens the pptm something is disabling the Macros and therefore erroring out the VBS code to not call and run the macro.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error but I only get that error when using `oApp.Run "UpdateandBreaklinks"` have you checked the spelling of the macro? can you run any other macro from your VBS. (ie. create a new one in the pptm and call it from the VBS)

Comment: Please look at the edit I Made in regards to further testing. Not sure what is causing this issue, if its something with VBS opening the pptm or not. ANy help is much appreciated. I am using Powerpoint 2013, if that makes a difference.